# Is there any Static Hazard?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-analysis, logic-gates, computer-architecture, logic-hazard

I read about Static Hazard. We know Static 1-hazard is: Input change causes output to go from 1 to 0 to 1.

My note covers a Circuit as follows:

[image]

My notes says: When `B=C=D=1`, for any changes in A values, it's probable to have Static Hazard 1.

But I think:

> for 1 to 0 transition of A static hazard 1 can be observed.  for 0 to
>
> 1 transition of A no hazard can be observed.

anyone could describe my sentence is correct or my note say the correct sentence. which of them is correct ? why? Thanks.

Comment: F is going to be 1 continuously, except maybe during transitions on A, in which case you have a race situation. What are you trying to do with this circuit?

Comment: I think either transition could be equally susceptible to the glitch caused by the race condition as you have one input to the final gate transitioning 0 to 1 while another transitions 1 to 0. Can you say why you do not believe the 0 to 1 transition of A is a problem?

Comment: @user1582568 would you please describe more for me? I think this is not obvious for me.

Comment: @user1582568 I Think Let the initial input be A=B=C=D=1, then P=Q=1, R = 0 and F = 1. I need more description

Comment: I don't know what P and Q are. The output of the top gate will be A. The output of the middle gate will be 1 always. The output of the bottom gate will be 'A (inverse of A). The right hand gate will always have a zero going in so will always have a 1 going out. As A changes, if the right hand gate responds to the high going transition first it will glitch low, as it will breifly see 3 1's at its inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of the top gate will be A. The output of the middle gate will be 1 (as it has a zero at one input). The output of the bottom gate will be 'A (inverse of A). The right hand gate will always have a zero going in so will always have a 1 going out. As A changes, if the right hand gate responds to the high going transition first it will glitch low, as it will briefly see 3 1's at its inputs.

The following chart shows the logic signals as A goes 0 to 1 to 0

[image]

Comment: If I called the output of first row gate P, second row Q and third row R, can I say: If at time t=0, the value of A and A' are toggled,

then at t=δ2 seconds, P=Q=1 and R=1 which will force F = 0
then at t=δ1 seconds, P=0 and Q=R=1 which will force F = 1

According to the logic the circuit's output should remain always at 1. But the output momentarily changes to 0 (for δ1−δ2
seconds) and then comes back to 1. And this is called static-1-hazard.

Comment: Yes, and this can happen on either transition. It will depend of whether there are any delays between the transition on A and 'A, and on the relative propagation delays (and threshold voltages) of the gates.

Comment: Is it possible to describe reverse transition? Thanks

Comment: Both transitions of A are symmetrical, forget Q, it is always 1. P is A and R is 'A. The only thing that changes for the right hand gate is that one input (P or R) goes from 1 to 0 while the other (R or P) goes from 0 to 1. Either situation is the same.

Comment: Sorry. I think Misunderstand. I thing got it, but No. Is it possible to make it clearer in answer part? thanks.

Comment: many hours, I thinking. please learn it me :)

Comment: I think you understand, you summarized it correctly in your previous comment, the output should always be 1 for any static input state of A, but it may glitch to 0 when A makes a transition (high or low going).

Comment: I approve it. but would you please add how you conclude these for any change of A value? please learn me. please. I confused. is it possible?

Comment: @MichleSipser, hope this helps, see edit to answer.

Comment: Question marks mean Hazard am I right?

Comment: Question marks mean the value is not determinable, could be high or low, so yes there is a hazzard.